# Regex search in Emacs for line not starting with semicolon

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I am trying to search forward in the current buffer for the first elisp function definition that is not a comment. I tried this:

```
(re-search-forward "[^;] *\(defun ")
```

but it matches comments anyway. Like the following line:

```
;; (defun test ()
```

Comment: Note, that the headline and your actual question in the body of your posting are not directly related. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space in `(defun test ()` actually matches `[^;]`.  Since you have `*`, another space is not needed.  You may want to use `[^;] +`.  However, you can use a negative lookbehind via

```
\(?<!;;)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I overlooked.. However, I am not sure how to use lookbehinds in Emacs.. Since the `(defun` without comment always is the first part of the line, I think I can use regex `\n(defun ` instead..

Comment: There are (sadly) no arbitrary zero-width look ahead/behind assertions in Emacs regular expressions. That syntax is not valid.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```lisp
 (catch 'found
  (let (match)
    (while (setq match (search-forward "(defun "))
      (when (null (syntax-ppss-context (syntax-ppss)))
        (throw 'found match)))
    nil))
```

It relies on the internal parser and the language syntax definition. It returns only the result of `search-forward` if point is not in a comment and not in a string. 
If you do not like the error in the case of a search without hits you can add `nil t` to the arguments of the `search-forward` command. Search with `re-search-forward` is also fine.

This also works for cases like:

```lisp
(defun test (args)
  "This function is defined with (defun test (args) ...)"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work nicely for me (tested in *scratch*):

```
(re-search-forward "^ *\(defun " nil t) ; hit C-x C-e after that
                                        ; closing parenthesis

;; (defun hi () )
(defun hola () )
```